# How to restrict share in textfield in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to restrict cut, copy, paste, share in text-filed.  By using below code i am able to restrict cut, copy & paste but not sure how to restrict share option.

is there any way to do that?

```
class RestrictedTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:))  || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)){
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** It's not possible for

Here is the list of all default actions:

```
paste:
cut:
copy:
select:
selectToHere:
selectAll:
paste:
delete:
_promptForReplace:
_transliterateChinese:
_insertDrawing:
_showTextStyleOptions:
_lookup:
_addShortcut:
_accessibilitySpeak:
_accessibilitySpeakLanguageSelection:
_accessibilityPauseSpeaking:
_share:
makeTextWritingDirectionRightToLeft:
makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight:
```

You can check for any of them if you want. But as you can see, some of theme, including `_share`, are private and your app will be rejected from AppStore if you touch them.

---

For private ones, you can do this like:

```
action.description == "_share:"
```

<sub>this method tricks AppStore auto review mechanism a bit but I'm not recommending it. ‍♂️</sub>

---

One thing You can do is to suppress all actions and include your needs instead:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    let validActions = [
        #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.toggleUnderline(_:)),
        #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(_:)),
        #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.makeTextWritingDirectionLeftToRight(_:))
    ]

    return validActions.contains(action)
}
```

<sub>Note that some of the actions are forced somehow and can not be overridden easily</sub>